# Select statement error in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a SELECT statement, but it's giving me an error in MYSQL. Not sure what I did wrong.

```
SELECT input, 
CASE WHEN input LIKE %is this to% THEN 10 
ELSE CASE WHEN input LIKE %this to you% THEN 12 
END END 
AS  'matches'
FROM tableName
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: please add the error-message in your question

Comment: single quotes missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT input,
CASE 
    WHEN input LIKE '%is this to%' THEN 10 
    WHEN input LIKE '%this to you%' THEN 12
ELSE 0
END AS  'matches'
FROM tableName
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT input 
CASE WHEN input LIKE '%is this to%' THEN 10 
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN input LIKE '%this to you%' THEN 12 
  END 
END 
AS  'matches'
FROM tableName
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Note the `'` (single quote)

Comment: The matches comes as null.